# How to know the message format of a jms queue

Tags: java, jms

I will post a message on a JMS queue, but it does not know what will be the format of this message. I send an xml? The service provider must provide me a xsd?

Comment: Yes. You have do agree on some format.

Comment: I don't see how the title relates to the question asked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Youy can use the "JMSType" standard property to indicate what kind of message is is, then the consumer can read that property and then handle correctly the payload based on the content of this property